# Mysql consumindo muita memoria

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu servidor está configurado para limitar uso de memoria do mysql em 70%,
a todo momento o mysql fica em 73.8% ou até 74%, mesmo quando quase ninguem está usando o sistema fica asssim, ai de vez em quando da erro em alguem usando, o erro é este :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso PDO e PHP, uma coisa que eu não faço é encerrar as conexões com banco porque me falaram que não precisava que já era automático, mas qual será o motivo dessa 'lotamento' da memória?

```html
<?php
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=banco", "usuario", "senha", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Comment: Minhas contas não bateram. Se está configurado para usar no máximo 70%, como ele fica constantemente em 73.8%?

Comment: Eu tambem não sei explicar, mas o maior problema é que ele ficando dando esse erro as vezes, e pelo menos eu suspeito que seja por causa da memória

Comment: Você tem como mostrar seu my.cnf?  Colocar innodb_buffer_pool_size nos 70% não faz que o server só utilice 70%.. as conexões consomem memória, queries consomem memória, etc..
Com o my.cnf do servidor talvez possa ajudar, mas aquele "74%" é normal